# How do I resolve the objectToSwitchTo error in Sitecore 9.3 with SXA on the ContentDelivery server?

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm currently experiencing an issue in SXA where the log reports an error and no search results are returned.

```
3764 08:00:38 WARN  Results endpoint exception
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: objectToSwitchTo
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Common.Switcher`2.Enter(TValue objectToSwitchTo)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService.GetQuery(SearchQueryModel searchQueryModel, String& indexName)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetResults(QueryModel model)
```

This appears to work fine in both **Standalone** and **ContentManagement** roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting issue and is somewhat related to another problem with the Asset Optimizer. In the **ContentDelivery** role SXA makes use of the "**shell**" site. When this is set to "**core**" the optimizer breaks. If you remove it then it creates an issue with search.

Below is a patch I got working to support both features:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="ContentDelivery">
    <sites>
      <site name="shell" set:database="web" />
      <site name="modules_shell" set:database="web" />
      <site name="login">
        <patch:delete />
      </site>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```